# how to print content of file by choosing it from list of another file python?

Tags: python

There is a  text file `list.txt` which contains the names of the files stored in the column to which you want to access, ie, let assigned to the variable  name of the file from the column and calculate the number of lines in it or just bring it to  print content. How to open and read the file line by line which contains the names  of the other file I understand, and how to assign them a name is not clear.

```
input_files = open ("list.txt")

for line in input_files.readlines():

    Read line by line with the names 1.txt, 2.txt
```

then somehow have to get access to them. ie to name and count the number of lines in a file?

Answer (score 1):

You can open those files exactly the same way you opened the first file.

```
input_files = open ("list.txt")

for line in input_files.readlines():    
    current_file = open(line.strip())
    # Do something with the file, such as reading its lines
    # Sample code dumps out filename followed by lines, followed by newline
    print line
    for x in current_file:
       print x
    print
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the files to be all `open()`'ed at once, I'd use a `dictionary` like so:

```
with open("list.txt") as input_files_file:
  input_files = {file : open(file) for file in
            input_files_file.read().splitlines()}
```

you can then access your files by their names if you know them (via `input_files['1.txt']`), extract their names if you don't know them (via `input_files.keys()`), or bulk-process all files (via `for file in input_files.values(): do_stuff()`).